# Mapping variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mapping

I have the following code that maps -75 to -90 into -90 to 0, and 90 to 75 into 0 to 90.  Is there a simpler way of doing this?  If there is an easy way of doing this, that would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
if ((rtiltLR <= -75) && (rtiltLR >= -90))
        {
            switch (rtiltLR)
            {
                case -75:
                    yval = -90;
                    break;
                case -76:
                    yval = -84;
                    break;
                case -77:
                    yval = -78;
                    break;
                case -78:
                    yval = -72;
                    break;
                case -79:
                    yval = -66;
                    break;
                case -80:
                    yval = -60;
                    break;
                case -81:
                    yval = -54;
                    break;
                case -82:
                    yval = -48;
                    break;
                case -83:
                    yval = -42;
                    break;
                case -84:
                    yval = -36;
                    break;
                case -85:
                    yval = -30;
                    break;
                case -86:
                    yval = -24;
                    break;
                case -87:
                    yval = -18;
                    break;
                case -88:
                    yval = -12;
                    break;
                case -89:
                    yval = -6;
                    break;
                case -90:
                    yval = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ((rtiltLR <= 90) && (rtiltLR >= 75))
        {
            switch (rtiltLR)
            {
                case 90:
                    yval = 0;
                    break;
                case 89:
                    yval = 6;
                    break;
                case 88:
                    yval = 12;
                    break;
                case 87:
                    yval = 18;
                    break;
                case 86:
                    yval = 24;
                    break;
                case 85:
                    yval = 30;
                    break;
                case 84:
                    yval = 36;
                    break;
                case 83:
                    yval = 42;
                    break;
                case 82:
                    yval = 48;
                    break;
                case 81:
                    yval = 54;
                    break;
                case 80:
                    yval = 60;
                    break;
                case 79:
                    yval = 66;
                    break;
                case 78:
                    yval = 72;
                    break;
                case 77:
                    yval = 78;
                    break;
                case 76:
                    yval = 84;
                    break;
                case 75:
                    yval = 90;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @downvoter Please explain why the downvote was given so that I can improve my question

Comment: Not my downvote...but IMO, you should be able to explain the thought process behind translating (for example) `-75` to `-90`.  Fun part is, from there, you're like 90% of the way done.

Comment: Ah, thanks @cHao!  Will make sure to include in future posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ((rtiltLR <= -75) && (rtiltLR >= -90))
    yval = (rtiltLR + 90) * -6;
else if ((rtiltLR <= 90) && (rtiltLR >= 75))
    yval = (90 - rtiltLR) * 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any relationship between your case statements and your results? If there is, then there certainly would be better ways to do this. If there isn't, you could use a JavaScript object with keys as your case statements and values as the results. For example:

```
var map = {
    "-75": -90,
    "-76": -84,
    // ...
    "76": 84,
    "75": 90
};
yval = map[rtiltLR.toString()]; // or just map[rtiltLR]


// or you could simplify things by computing negative values
var map = {
    "90": 0,
    // only positive values
    "75": 90
};
yval = rtiltLR > 0 ? map[rtiltLR] : -map[-rtiltLR];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the yValue can be calculated, then you obviously should do that on the fly.

If there really is a long set of arbitrary mappings, I would suggest a hashmap:

```
yValueLookup = {};
yValueLookup[-75] = -90;
yValueLookup[-76] = -84;
// etc
yValueLookup[89] = 6;
yValueLookup[90] = 0;



function getYvalue(rtiltLR) {
   return yValueLookup[rtiltR];
}
```